# Azure Data Explorer - Power BI. Fail to read from external tables

Tags: powerbi, azure-data-explorer, kql

When connecting from Power BI to Azure Data Explorer (ADX) I see all artifacts, yet when I select an external table I get the following error.

[image]

Is there a way to connect and visualize external tables in Power BI?
I see a similar problem when using Tableau (using the synapse analytics connector) where I see only the internal tables.

Are external tables queryable outside the ADX portal or API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AzureDataExplorer PBI Connector doesn't support external tables as part of the UI navigation at the moment.

However, you can connect to external tables by providing them explicitly:

```
= AzureDataExplorer.Contents(
      "<cluster>",
      "<database>",
      "external_table('<ExternalTableName>')",
      [MaxRows=null, MaxSize=null, NoTruncate=null, AdditionalSetStatements=null])
```

For example:

```
= AzureDataExplorer.Contents(
      "help",
      "Samples",
      "external_table('TaxiRides') | take 10",
      [MaxRows=null, MaxSize=null, NoTruncate=null, AdditionalSetStatements=null])
```